# Regex to match the pattern split with slash

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql

I want to query the database column with regex to match the string like the following...

```
1. qwge1/dg2/hjetg3
2. tahry4/rtg5
3. jtyg6
```

How to split the zero to multiple slashes and match the `[a-z]+[0-9]` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
^([a-z]+[0-9](/|$))+$
```

The inner expression, `[a-z]+[0-9](/|$)`, describes a series of alphabetic characters followed by a digit, then by a slash or the end of the string. This expression may be repeated 1 to N times, followed by the end of the string.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=632124b76edef6d9efbc89cd4efa8197)** - I added a few non-matching strings to your sample data:

```
select val, val ~ '^([a-z]+[0-9](/|$))+$'
from (values 
    ('qwge1/dg2/hjetg3'), 
    ('tahry4/rtg5'), 
    ('jtyg6'), 
    ('abc'), 
    ('qwge1/dg2/hjetg'),
    ('qwge1/dg2/3')
) x(val)
```

```
val              | ?column?
:--------------- | :-------
qwge1/dg2/hjetg3 | t       
tahry4/rtg5      | t       
jtyg6            | t       
abc              | f       
qwge1/dg2/hjetg  | f   
qwge1/dg2/3      | f
```